# convert node server with react build folder into a single exe file

Tags: node.js, exe

I have built a react app and node server.Later I just build the react client and made it run on node server itself. Now I want to make my node server into a single exe file.

My server folder structure

server

---build

---node_modules

---index.js

---ecosystem.config.js

---package-lock.json

---package.json

---pm2

I tried to create the exe file using pkg, but I'm getting the folllowing error

```
Error: File or directory 'C:\**\server\build\index.html' was not included into executable at compilation stage. Please recompile adding it as asset or script.
    at error_ENOENT (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:657:19)
    at findNativeAddonForStat (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1445:32)
    at statFromSnapshot (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1468:25)
    at Object.stat (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1494:5)
    at SendStream.sendFile (C:\snapshot\server\node_modules\send\index.js:717:6)
    at SendStream.pipe (C:\snapshot\server\node_modules\send\index.js:591:8)
    at sendfile (C:\snapshot\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1130:8)
    at ServerResponse.sendFile (C:\snapshot\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:449:3)
    at C:\snapshot\server\index.js
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\snapshot\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

I want to have a exe file which should contain the build folder and server files